# Polymer: How to loop and render HTML to screen

Tags: polymer

I am working on a widget that pulls third party information from a database using json. Once the information has been collected, I plan to loop through the information and create the required HTML code and insert this into the template via a {{variable}}

Now I am getting an unexpected result. When I do this, the html is being displayed as text.

Here is some sudo code of the issue:

```
       <polymer-element name="loop-element">
            <template>
                  {{customerList}}
            </template>
            <script>
                Polymer('loop-element', {
                   ready: function() {
                       this.loadCustomerList();
                   }
                   customerList:"Loading customer list...",

                   loadCustomerList: function() {
                       CustomerNameArray[] = //Get the array from jSon file
                       i = 0;
                       do {
                           this.customerList = "<div>" + customerNameArray[i] + "</div>";
                       } while (customerNameArray[i]);
                   }

                });

            </script>
        </polymer-element>
```

Essentially the DIV's are not being rendered, instead they are being printed to the screen as text:

```
"<div>Name 1</div>" "<div>Name 2</div>" ... n
```

Instead of:

```
Name 1
Name 2
Name n...
```

You can see a JSBin example here: http://jsbin.com/tituzibu/1/edit

Can anyone recommend how to go about outputting a list to the template?

Comment: You cannot bind HTML directly to DOM. As as security precaution it's always escaped. If you need to do this today, you must do it imperatively, 'this.innerHTML = someHtml;' or equivalent.

Answer (score 12):

> Polymer v.1.0

```
/* relative path to polymer.html*/
<link rel="import" href="../bower_components/polymer/polymer.html">

<dom-module id="employee-list">
    <style>
        /* CSS rules for your element */
    </style>
    <template>
        <div> Employee list: </div>
        <template is="dom-repeat" items="{{employees}}">
            <div>First name: <span>{{item.first}}</span></div>
            <div>Last name: <span>{{item.last}}</span></div>
        </template>
    </template>
</dom-module>

<script>
    Polymer({
        is: 'employee-list',
        ready: function() {
            this.employees = [
                {first: 'Bob', last: 'Smith'},
                {first: 'Sally', last: 'Johnson'}
            ];
        }
    });
</script>
```

[doc](https://www.polymer-project.org/1.0/docs/devguide/templates.html#dom-repeat)

Answer (score 10):

You should use Polymer's DOM-based data-binding features rather than creating the markup yourself.

```
<template repeat="{{customer, i in customers}}">
  <div>{{i}}, {{customer.name}}</div>
</template>
```

http://www.polymer-project.org/docs/polymer/databinding.html#an-example

Comment: Thank you Eric, this worked a treat. I think a big part of the struggle is getting to understand the terms used with Polymer development and how to search for the correct reference material.

Comment: A glossary isn't a bad idea. What other things would make your life easier? I'd like to know so we can improve the docs. Feel free to jot down an issue: https://github.com/polymer/docs/issues?state=open

Comment: Well, if Polymer were on CodeCademy.com that would be a great start. The method of teaching is so simple that it works, and it works well. Definitely a glossary of terms would be awesome, half the time I don't know what to call the {{thingy}} or point out the "directive part" or understand the order that things load... so far its been trial and error (but fun). I still don't know how to use the Polymer-Project.com site :) I usually Google: "term + Polymer Project" and hope it finds the right page on the site. But what I would really love would be a list of simple to complex tutorials.

Comment: The repeat="{{key, value in dictionary}}" only appears to work in <template> elements.  https://www.polymer-project.org/docs/polymer/template.html

Answer (score 1):

Maybe a little late...
If you want to stick to your approach you could use `this.injectBoundHTML`:

```
 <polymer-element name="loop-element">
            <template>
                  <div id='customerList'> </div> 
            </template>
            <script>
                Polymer('loop-element', {
                   ready: function() {
                       this.loadCustomerList();
                   }
                   customerList:"Loading customer list...",

                   loadCustomerList: function() {
                       CustomerNameArray[] = //Get the array from jSon file
                       i = 0;
                       do {
                           this.customerList = "<div>" + customerNameArray[i] + "</div>";
                       } while (customerNameArray[i]);
                      this.injectBoundHTML( this.customerList, 
                         this.$.customerList);
                   }

                });

            </script>
        </polymer-element>
```

However the first approach is better..

Answer (score 1):

In Polymer 3.0 you can do the following:

```
<dom-repeat items="{{customers}}">
  <template>
    {{item.name}}
  </template>
</dom-repeat>
```

Any list is binded to the `items` property of `dom-repeat`, and `item` within the template is used to represent the object from the list. You can read more about the `dom-repeat` on the Polymer 3.0 API reference page [here](https://www.polymer-project.org/3.0/docs/api/elements/dom-repeat).