# How do I use dom-repeat in Polymer binding to a dictionary

Tags: polymer

I am trying to bind to data below which is a dictionary

```
<template is="dom-repeat" items="{{data}}">
</template>
```

I have found a similar question here [Polymer: How to loop and render HTML to screen](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22974366/polymer-how-to-loop-and-render-html-to-screen)

```
<template repeat="{{customer, i in customers}}">
  <div>{{i}}, {{customer.name}}</div>
</template>
```

but I am not sure if this applies to Polymer 1.0 and cannot find anything in the doc.

How do I do this in 1.0?

Cheers

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you have in the first example is correct for Polymer 1.0. [Here](https://www.polymer-project.org/1.0/docs/devguide/templates.html#dom-repeat) is the documentation for the template repeat (dom-repeat).

```
<template is="dom-repeat" items="{{data}}">
    <div>
        <span>{{index}}</span> <span>{{item}}</span>
    </div>
</template>
```

Comment: is `data` an array or a dictionary?

Comment: `data` would be an array. `dom-repeat` is for iterating over an array.