# Returned the last value instead of the correct one

Tags: javascript, aurelia

What I want is that each name will get its associate value, but the following code will print the all the values on each loop then it stops at the last value.

Home.html

```
<template>
   <div repeat.for="name of names">
    ${getValue(name)}
    <p>Hello ${value}</p>
   </div>
</template>
```

Home.js

```
export class Home {
    names = ["one", "two", "three"];

    constructor() {
        this.getValue();
        this.value = "";
    }

    getData() {
        return httpClient.fetch('example.com/api/v')
            .then(response => response.json())
            .then(data => {
                return data;
            });
    }

    getValue(name) {
        this.getData()
            .then(data => this.value = data.name);
    }
}
```

Actual results:

```
Hello value3 //It prints value1 value2 then stops at value3
Hello value3 //It prints value1 value2 then stops at value3
Hello value3 //It prints value1 value2 then stops at value3
```

Expected results:

```
Hello value1
Hello value2
Hello value3
```

Comment: See this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22974366/polymer-how-to-loop-and-render-html-to-screen

Comment: You're running three asynchronous calls, and each of them will overwrite `this.value`. So whichever call finishes last will determine the final `value`, which is then displayed in all three paragraphs. Also note that `data.name` will ignore the `name` parameter; for that to work you need `data[name]`.

Comment: @Tridev Mishra How is it related to this?

Comment: @Chris G Can you tell me how to prevent that?

Comment: Run the `fetch` once, when the component is created/mounted, then store the result in an array variable. In your template code, iterate over the array and use the actual item: `<p>Hello ${name}</p>`

Comment: Beside @ChrisG 's comment, you can also do this https://codesandbox.io/s/flamboyant-morning-npphu . Note that you shouldn't call `getData()` inside the constructor, if it's a necessary business logic, maybe separate. Or if trivial call, maybe do it during `bind` or `attached`