# How to loop through data from an API call and render each to a div?

Tags: javascript, html, node.js

I'm trying to figure out how to loop through my API data and render data to each div. Specifically, to have info from each movie in its own div.

```js
const loopData = () => {

  let apiCall = `https://ghibliapi.herokuapp.com/films`;

  fetch(apiCall)
    .then(response => response.json())
    .then(data => {
      for (let i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
        let obj = data[i];

        console.log(obj.title);
      }

      ;
    })
};

loopData()
```

```html
<div id="main">
  <div></div>
  <div></div>
  <div></div>
  <div></div>
</div>
```

Here is what my data looks like:

[image: Data from console]

Comment: Check if this helps: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22974366/polymer-how-to-loop-and-render-html-to-screen

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Create a div using loop](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11398522/create-a-div-using-loop)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- All you need is a helper function that handles the creation of your desired element with the data you provided.
- I have created the function `createMyCustomeElement(data, id)`, this takes two arguments one for the data and the second one is the id of the element in which we will append created legal HTML.
- Just for more readable way I have changed `for-loop` to `forEach` loop.

```js
const loopData = () => {

  let apiCall = `https://ghibliapi.herokuapp.com/films`;

  fetch(apiCall)
    .then(response => response.json())
    .then(data => {
      data.forEach(val => {
        // calling createMyCustomeElement that takes data and id of element in which data gonna append
        createMyCustomeElement(val, "#main");
      })
    })
};

loopData()
// this function will handle in which element you want to insert and how you want to create element as per your need.
function createMyCustomeElement(data, id) {
  const parent = document.querySelector(id);
  let createdTitle = `<div class="card">
  <h5>${data.title}</h5>
  <img src="${data.image}"/>
  <p>${data.description}</p>
  </div>`;
  parent.innerHTML += createdTitle;
}
```

```css
* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  font-family: "Jost";
}

#main {
  margin: 20px;
}

.card {
  padding: 20px;
  box-shadow: 0 0 15px 0 #b4b4b465;
  margin-bottom: 10px;
}

.card img {
  object-fit: cover;
  width: 100%;
  height: 200px;
}
```

```html
<div id="main">
</div>
```

Answer (score 2):

You can create `div` elements when you receive the `data` from `API` and add into them `textNode` to the movie's title and then append them as children to the `div` whose has `.main` id.

```js
const loopData = () => {

  let apiCall = `https://ghibliapi.herokuapp.com/films`;
  const mainEle = document.getElementById('main');

  fetch(apiCall)
    .then(response => response.json())
    .then(data => {
      for (let i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
        let obj = data[i];

        const div = document.createElement('div');
        let textNode = document.createTextNode(obj.title);
        div.appendChild(textNode)
        main.appendChild(div);
      }

      ;
    })
};

loopData()
```

```html
<div id="main"></div>
```

Also, you can use `reduce` method.

```js
const loopData = () => {

  let apiCall = `https://ghibliapi.herokuapp.com/films`;
  const mainEle = document.getElementById('main');

  fetch(apiCall)
    .then(response => response.json())
    .then(data => {
      const html = data.reduce((acc, movie) => {
        acc += `<div>${movie.title}</div>`
        return acc;
      }, '')
      main.innerHTML = html
    })
};

loopData()
```

```html
<div id="main"></div>
```